# Get android phone books

Tags: android, android-contacts

I need some help, because I can't find any solutions on Google :-(

Is there a easy way to get the names of the phone books on my device. I want fill a spinner with these values. So I need a result which contains entries like: SIM, Google, Local, etc.

These values are accessible by the Contacts Provider (I think in ContactsContract.RawContacts) and named as ACCOUNT_TYPE and ACCOUNT_NAME. But I think it couldn't be the solution to get the values with a cursor from the Contacts Provider.

Thank you so much for any suggestions.

Comment: "But I think it couldn't be the solution to get the values with a cursor from the Contacts Provider" -- using `ContactsContract` would certainly seem to be the correct answer. What problems did you encounter when implementing that? Why do you think that "it couldn't be the solution"?

Comment: I think there must be a easier way than iterating over all contacts like a provider which returns the account types directly. I mean something that's like a sql query with a GROUP BY ... But if this is the prefered way then i know what to do :-)

Comment: Ah, now I see what you mean. Off the cuff, I don't have a great solution for you, though -- sorry!

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<Person> getContactList(){
        ArrayList<Person> contactList = new ArrayList<Person>();

        Uri contactUri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
        String[] PROJECTION = new String[] {
                ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER,
        };
        String SELECTION = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "='1'";
        Cursor contacts = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, SELECTION, null, null);


        if (contacts.getCount() > 0)
        {
            while(contacts.moveToNext()) {
                Person aContact = new Person();
                int idFieldColumnIndex = 0;
                int nameFieldColumnIndex = 0;
                int numberFieldColumnIndex = 0;

                String contactId = contacts.getString(contacts.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

                nameFieldColumnIndex = contacts.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME);
                if (nameFieldColumnIndex > -1)
                {
                    aContact.setName(contacts.getString(nameFieldColumnIndex));
                }

                PROJECTION = new String[] {Phone.NUMBER};
                final Cursor phone = managedQuery(Phone.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, Data.CONTACT_ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(contactId)}, null);
                if(phone.moveToFirst()) {
                    while(!phone.isAfterLast())
                    {
                        numberFieldColumnIndex = phone.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER);
                        if (numberFieldColumnIndex > -1)
                        {
                            aContact.setPhoneNum(phone.getString(numberFieldColumnIndex));
                            phone.moveToNext();
                            TelephonyManager mTelephonyMgr;
                            mTelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                            if (!mTelephonyMgr.getLine1Number().contains(aContact.getPhoneNum()))
                            {
                                contactList.add(aContact);  
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                phone.close();
            }

            contacts.close();
        }

        return contactList;
    }
```

Person class:

```
public class Person {
    String myName = "";
    String myNumber = "";

    public String getName() {
        return myName;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        myName = name;
    }

    public String getPhoneNum() {
        return myNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNum(String number) {
        myNumber = number;
    }
}
```